# "As everyone" vs. "like everyone"

Tags: word-choice

Which sentence is more correct?

> 1. **As** everyone I dream about travelling to other countries.
> 2. **Like** everyone I dream about travelling to other countries.

Comment: Related: [“Like” versus “as”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16039/like-versus-as).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence I would use "like".

[Like vs. As](http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Like_vs_As.htm)

> We generally use LIKE and AS to make
>   comparisons.
>
> **LIKE**
>
> The structure of the sentence is
>   usually: VERB + LIKE + NOUN / PRONOUN.
>
> He speaks like a native speaker. 
>   She looks like a supermodel.
>
> **AS**
>
> The structure of the sentence is
>   usually: AS + SUBJECT + VERB.
>
> Nobody sings as she does. They went to the
>   party as they were.
>
> It is very common
>   in American English to use LIKE
>   instead of AS. However, it is
>   generally considered informal to use
>   it in this way. We play football like
>   champions do.
>
> Another use of AS is to
>   say what the role/function of a
>   person/thing is. He started work as a
>   carpenter. She used the tapestry as a
>   decoration in her living room.
>
> **LIKE vs. AS**
>
> Be careful, in similar sentences that
>   use LIKE and AS, the meanings of each
>   sentence are very different. For
>   example: As your boss, I must warn you
>   to be careful. (I am your boss.) Like
>   your boss, I must warn you to be
>   careful. (I am not your boss, but
>   he/she and I have similar attitudes.)

Comment: Thank you for your full answer! Now I know the difference! :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer ***like***
Also, you need a comma.

> Like everyone, I dream about travelling to other countries.

Or you could use

> As everyone does, I dream about travelling to other countries.

Comment: No problem. You could thank me by upvoting me. Or acepting this answer. haha. I kid, I kid.

Answer (score 1):

The use of *like* and *as* is often confused. *like* is a preposition whereas *as* is a conjunction.  What you have to do, in practice, is to use *like* when no verb follows. You can see, in fact, the examples by Michael:

> Like everyone, I dream about
>   travelling to other countries.
>
> As everyone does, I dream about
>   travelling to other countries.

In your case, the correct sentence is

> Like everyone I dream about travelling
>   to other countries.