# If saying 'Why can't I ...?' is correct, would 'Why cannot I ...?' be technically correct?

Tags: questions, negation, modal-verbs

> Why can't I ...?

is perfectly correct grammar as far as I can tell. But what happens if the contraction is removed,

> Why cannot I ...?

This sounds bizarre, but would this be technically correct grammar?

Comment: It's perfectly correct; It just sounds  old-fashioned to use the uncontracted form in this context.

Comment: No, it's not "technically correct". There is no such category. But it's not grammatical, either; that's why it sounds bizarre. That's what ungrammatical sentences sound like. The reason is that contractions **can't** be just unpacked ad lib. Once they're contracted (by a very technical rule), there's no rule to uncontract them -- they're simple words now, and they can get moved, as contractions, but not as compounds. Subject-auxiliary inversion (another technical rule) only works on single words, not on _cannot_, which is two. See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/181164/15299

Comment: I believe a comment from Professor Emeritus John Lawler (I'll have to amend it now)  is relevant here: "[Even if a certain example] [may be] totally grammatical, that [may be] the only good thing you can say about it." Idiomaticity (how practised native speakers actually use the language) is probably even more important than grammaticality, and certainly drives grammaticality over time.

Comment: When you say it sounds bizarre, how exactly do you pronounce it? At least to me, "Why cannot I ..." sounds more natural (if not entirely natural) when the stress is on the first syllable rather than the second.

Comment: @JohnLawler - _Why cannot I_ was perfectly acceptable in the 19th century. See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=why+cannot+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhy%20can%20not%20I%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwhy%20can%20not%20I%3B%2Cc0), for example _Why cannot I keep my mind on a book for one moment? Why can I not write two sentences together?_ (Trollope: Framley Parsonage)

Comment: @KateBunting - Indeed it was. But it's the 21st century now. Language changes and people don't talk that way any more. People trying to write like Trollope still write like that, of course, but they don't talk that way.

Comment: No, of course not - but that doesn't make it ungrammatical, just unidiomatic (as I originally commented!).

Comment: @KateBunting There is an interesting discussion on the history of _"Why cannot..."_ in the answers to the old question [Is it incorrect to say, "Why cannot....?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50251/is-it-incorrect-to-say-why-cannot).

Comment: @KateBunting your nGram gets more interesting if you [add the alternative](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=why+cannot+I%2Cwhy+can+I+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhy%20can%20not%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhy%20can%20I%20not%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: English grammar is just complicated that way. It is what it's.

Comment: The problem here is that there's not really such a thing as "technically correct grammar".  English doesn't have an official arbiter of correct grammar, such as exists for some other languages.  There's "what people actually say" and "what people actually write", and "what people used to write at some point in history", and "what my favourite grammar textbook sanctions".  But none of those are the same as "technically correct".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you remove the contraction, you need to say:

> Why can I not...?

just like with the auxiliaries *do* or *have*

> Why do you not continue...?, Why have you not completed the task?

[YourDictionary](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/vs/cannot-vs-can-not-vs-cant-differences-explained.html) explains:

> In question form, the noun or pronoun comes between ***can*** and ***not***. For example:
>
> - ***Can we not** discuss* this today?

Note that ***can+pronoun+not+verb*** sounds formal, even somewhat dated in certain contexts. The KJV Bible uses it:

> ... ***can ye not** discern* the signs of the times? (Matt. 16:3 KJV)

Also, this formula helps when you want to emphasise the NOT.

*Cannot* used before the subject in rhetorical questions is possible, but not that common. You will find it in books dating from before 1850's or in poetry (see [Googlebooks](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Why%20cannot%20I%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsZRjsG-7oETVoRbrkJXxK3OmYCSow:1662202574716&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi604qQu_j5AhWJiVwKHT5OBb84ChD8BSgBegQIARAL&biw=1536&bih=743&dpr=1.25)).

Comment: "just with the auxiliaries **do** or **have**"...it's also worth noting that the non-contracted version of ***Won't you listen**?* is ***Will you not listen**?*, not ***Will not you listen**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just noticed from your quote that I omitted a word by mistake. I meant "just **like** with the auxiliaries"...

Comment: I didn't notice the *missing* word before, but now you're made me look at it again, I'll just point out that [most native speakers would use ***as*** rather than ***like*** there.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=just+as+with+the%2Cjust+like+with+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjust%20as%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjust%20like%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0) I might be a bit of an old fuddy-duddy, but ***like*** there sounds a bit "common" (uneducated) to me. Dunno if that specific usage has ever been raised on ELU/ELL though.

Comment: I think the message gets across with "like" as well, so I will leave it. Together with your comment it might satisfy some people's curiosity :)

Comment: At your level of English, you don't really need people like *(**such as**?!)* me telling you how you *should* phrase things! As implied by the chart I linked to above, ***like*** has significantly gained traction in recent decades. Perhaps the reality is that your version is up-and-coming, and mine is on the way to becoming "dated / quaint"! :) It's not an easy usage to search for in existing questions, but if I was reasonably confident it *hasn't* been asked before (and wouldn't get closed as POB) I'd quite like to know just how "acceptable" ***like*** is to younger speakers here.

Comment: Yes, I would actually encourage you to ask this question if there is no duplicate. It piqued my curiosity already...

Comment: I was trying to encourage *you* to find an earlier duplicate! :)

Comment: Guess what I am doing right now! Here is [something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16039/like-versus-as).

Comment: Well found! I guess *syntactically* speaking the key point is *"Like" is a preposition; "as" is a conjunction.* But in practice, [as Jon answers there,](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/16091/2637) ***only grammarians will notice** if you [use **like** as a "conjunction"].* Dang! I didn't even realise I was a "grammarian"! :)

Comment: There you go! I am glad my _syntactical transgression_ deepened your self-knowledge :))

Comment: It seems to me the "can we not" form of the question is asking not to discuss something today. That is how I would ask at least, whereas "can't we" is unambiguously asking to discuss today.

Comment: @CassLopez Indeed, there is difference of meaning between "Can't we" and "Can we not" (which I touched upon in passing when I mentioned the stress of NOT), but this is an interesting topic that should be discussed in a different question, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

When forming question, the auxiliary verb is moved to the front of the clause from its normal position:

- She **can** sing.
- **Can** she sing?

*Not* can only move from its normal position if it's stuck to this auxiliary. It's the auxiliary that's carrying *not* round to the front of the sentence. It can only do this if they're joined together.

If *not* isn't contracted, it must stay in the same position it has in a normal declarative sentence. Below the parts that invert are in light font, the rest of the sentence is in bold. In sentence (3) we see *not* moved away from it's normal position because it's attached to the auxiliary verb. It's sandwiched between the auxiliary and the subject:

1. Tom does **not like Sally** (normal negative sentence)
2. Does Tom **not like Sally** (no contraction, *not* in normal declarative sentence position)
3. Does**n't** Tom **like Sally** (contracted with auxiliary, *n't* appears in pre-subject position)

The examples above are yes/no questions for simplicity, but exactly the same things holds in open questions like the OP's too.

Comment: i.e. She does not sing -> Does she not sing? ///// She doesn't sing -> Doesn't she sing?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, prezackerly so.